# How to delete Size, Type, Date Modified in QFileSystemModel?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I use the `QFileSystemModel`, but I just want to show the tree directory in `QTreeView`. I dont want to show Size,Type and Date Modified.

[image]

This is my code:

```
def setFileModel(self):
    self.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
    self.folders_lv.setModel(self.model)

    self.model.setRootPath(self.directory)
    self.folders_lv.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.directory))
    self.folders_lv.expand(self.model.index(self.directory))
    self.model.setNameFilters(["*"])
```

Comment: Would you please review the questions you have asked and consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and/or [upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400) some of the answers you have got for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [hide the columns](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#hideColumn) that you don't want shown:

```
    self.folders_lv.hideColumn(1)
    self.folders_lv.hideColumn(2)
```

(NB: make sure you do this *after* the model has been initialized).